# Unable to Open Jupyter Notebook - Distutils Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to open Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda. I tried using the prompt: jupyter notebook and jupyter-notebook and the following error appears:

Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I also removed the other installation of Python I had along with VS Code. No luck there either.

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: Is there some specific reason why are you using Anaconda?  Anaconda promotes itself as the official package management for Jupyter.  It's not.  It is extremely easy to install python and Jupyter without Anaconda.  Anaconda creates a big layer of unknown between the user and the base software.  Once away from Anaconda, it's easy to get answers to specific questions about python or Jupyter, etc...

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I'm new to Python and thought Anaconda was a good option to use Jupyter with. I tried using Jupyter on VS Code and I'm getting a different error. It's asking me to install pykernel, but fails to install it for some reason..